# ASP.NET Core JWTBearerAuthentication not authenticating/authorizing properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Issue I'm having is when I use `signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("secret")), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)` in `TokenController` I get a `500 Internal Server Error` at `var encoded_token = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);`.

I believe that may have something to do with proper certificates.

When I remove that line and go to `http://localhost:61571/api/Users` I get a `401 Unauthorized` status code.  The JWT that gets created seems to work fine when I plug it in to an online decoder.

So my questions are:

1. Why is `JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);` giving me a 500 Internal Server Error?
2. Why am I getting a 401 Unauthorized code?

I'm using VS2017 with ASP.NET Core 1.1.  This is all running on IIS Express in VS2017.

### Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ToDoApi.Services;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;
using System;

namespace ToDoApi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ToDoApi.Data.ApplicationDbContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddSingleton<IUserService, UserService>();

            // Add framework services.
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            env.EnvironmentName = EnvironmentName.Development;

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
            }


            var keyAsBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("secret");

            var options = new JwtBearerOptions
            {
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                AutomaticChallenge = true,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("secret")),
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

                    ValidAudience = "http://localhost:61571",
                    ValidateAudience = true,

                    ValidIssuer = "http://localhost:61571",
                    ValidateIssuer = true,

                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                }
            };

            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options);

            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

### TokenController.cs

```
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ToDoApi.Models;

namespace ToDoApi.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class TokenController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Token([FromBody] User model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            var user = new User { ID = 1, Username = "username", Password = "password" };//await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);

            //if (user == null || _passwordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(user, user.PasswordHash, model.Password) != PasswordVerificationResult.Success)
            //{
            //    return BadRequest();
            // }

            var claims = new Claim[]
 {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, "username"),
                 new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, "40fdb6d4-1ea5-49af-9fcc-edb9e8d18dd5"),
                 new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow).ToUniversalTime().ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer64)
 };
            var token = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: "http://localhost:61571",
                audience: "http://localhost:61571",
                claims: claims,
                notBefore: DateTime.UtcNow,
                expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
                signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("secret")), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
            );

            var encoded_token = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
            return Ok(new
            {
                token = encoded_token,
                expiration = token.ValidTo
            });
        }
    }
}
```

### UsersController.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ToDoApi.Models;
using ToDoApi.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;

namespace ToDoApi.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class UsersController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IUserService _userService;

        public UsersController(IUserService userService)
        {
            _userService = userService;
        }

        // GET: api/Users
        [Authorize]
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()
        {
            return _userService.ListAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are getting 500 code may be that you use too short secret key for `HMACSHA256`. Try to use string with at least 128 bit size (16 symbols).

For the 401 code it depends. If you get a 500 error when trying to generate token, then what token do you use in the Authorization header?

Another tricky reason for 401 may be that you're using `Bearer` authorization along with Cookies and Identity Framework. In that case you need to call `UseJwtBearerAuthentication` before `UseIdentity`. But from code sample you provided, it seems like you do not use Identity.